# DynamoDB throttling even with spare capacity

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am getting throttled update requests on a DynamoDB table even though there is provisioned capacity to spare.

[image: throttled dynamodb]

What could be causing this?

I have a hunch that this must be related to "hot keys" in the table, but I want to get an opinion before going down that rabbit-hole. If that is the problem, any suggestions on tools or processes to help visualize/debug the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: How's your read capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Frequent updates to the same hash key but different range key?**

i.e. `userId + timeStamp`

`userId` = Hash Key

`timeStamp` = Range Key

e.g.

```
user1 + 2016-06-23:23:00:01
user1 + 2016-06-23:23:00:02
user1 + 2016-06-23:23:00:03
user1 + 2016-06-23:23:00:04
user1 + 2016-06-23:23:00:05
```

This causes hotkeys.

There is not a non-invasive techniques that i know of. If you have access to the code base to make changes, i suggest **logging** the hash and range key, this is one way you can determine if you are having hot rows / hot keys.

Comment: This is definitely the problem. Is there a published recommended max # of writes/second/partition?

Comment: :) i can't find this as a published information but having done some performance tests 3 years back, each row should have a tolerance of 300 - 600 read / write per seconds before throwing Provisioned Throughput Exceeded exceptions